# Custom Homepage For Blogger

Tags: html, xml, blogger

I've been trying to figure out how some folks do a custom homepage that works properly with just template code. Here is what I have tried:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
// code
<b:else/>
// code
</b:if>
```

This works fine and dandy, except you cannot edit/add widgets to the "admin > layout" area of Blogger. It will only show the widget section within the `<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>` and `<b:else/>` tags.

I could use CSS & `display:none` to achieve the same effect, and it'll be editable via the admin area, but then when viewing any part of the site it will be loading unnecessary content that won't be seen, increasing load time.

I'v even tried:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
```

for the homepage, and for all others I used:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>
```

This helps reduce the amount of unseen content to be loaded, but it breaks the "preview" of posts. It will only show the homepage information on previews, not the actual post that needs previewing.

How can I do this **properly**? I know it can be done, because I've seen it done. There are Blogger themes for sale that do this. For the life of me, I cannot figure this out...

Comment: What is the actual output you are trying to achieve.?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear. To create a homepage through the template that works without any major drawbacks. I am able to make the homepage through the template with various methods, but each method has it's drawbacks. I have seen some authors do it without any drawbacks...

Comment: what is different from ur homepage and posts pages?Number of widgets?or even the dimensions of the widets?or something even else?

Comment: There are no blog posts on the homepage. Only widget sections exclusive to the homepage.

Comment: Have you tried searching for what you want changed in the HTML layout, and changing locked value to false (then removing the unwanted item on the template page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the solution as I haven't found any faults with it yet.

To display on everywhere except the homepage:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl || data:view.isLayoutMode || data:view.isPreview'>
    your code here
</b:if>
```

This is great for loading sections with gadgets everywhere except the homepage. Although its a shame it took me 6 years to figure it out.

EDIT: as you can see from the conditions, it won't show on homepage(index), admin layout mode, or post preview.

Answer (score 0):

**For Widgets**

In your template code include all widgets.This would cause the "layout" section to have all widgets.....now we would use conditional tags to decide whether we want have them only on the home page,post page or any specific url/tag page,etc. Tutorial to do so is [here](http://helplogger.blogspot.in/2012/03/hideshow-widgetsgadgets-in.html)

**For Everything else**

Putting the code `<data:post.body/>` in the template will return the Actual Post content.

So this code

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
<data:post.body/>
</b:if>
```

would bring post content only on posts pages and not on home page

Comment: There is a problem with this method, as I have tried it already. If I use '<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>', then there is no "Blog Page". In other words, if I visit "mydomain.com/search/blog", no blog posts appear. The goal is to create a homepage, but still having a page with blog listings or "blog page".

Answer (score 0):

I Probably got your Question.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'> <data:post.body/> </b:if>
```

You do not need to have even a single post on the homepage and want to have them all on the label named blog.
[here](http://www.yesiamblogger.com)
Hope you can find all the things you need here.

I tried another thing to do it.

Goto Blogger >> Dashboard
Settings >> posts & comments
and set 0 posts to be shown on the homepage. Now hide the No post text with coding as told in above answer. Show those posts on a label page like blog.blogspot.com/search/label/blog by putting all your posts in that label.

I am damn sure this worked.